# How to filter interpolated results in Angular CLI

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-cli

I am using ngFor to iterate and render results in my HTML on the front end

One of my results is an Error message which I simply render as:

```
{{result.Error}}
```

However the model has now changed and on some scenarios the Error Message can now contain a JSON object so the page is rendering the full object for errors containing a JSON value.

How can I filter this result by checking to see if its JSON and if it is  return just the value of ***errorMessage*** and if its not JSON just return the full message

Thanks

Comment: `{{result.Error.errorMessage ? result.Error.errorMessage : result.Error}}`

Comment: any errors in the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either add an inline template condition, or use a method in your component to add additional logic.

For the inline template condition:

**In your HTML:**

```
{{ result.Error.errorMessage ? result.Error.errorMessage : result.Error }}
```

As a method (for more complex logic):

**In your HTML:**

```
{{ checkError(result.Error) }}
```

**In your TS file:**

```
checkError(error: any) {
    return result.Error.errorMessage ? result.Error.errorMessage : result.Error;
}
```

Comment: thanks i went for the method approach so i can change any future business logic in one location rather than worrying about the view.

Comment: Yes, but please note my answer on the following question regarding change detection strategies: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54980693/call-async-functions-retunes-observable-from-html-template/54981553#54981553

Answer (score 0):

Take advantage of JS and it's way of testing strings :

```js
let error = 'some error from string';

function showError() {
  console.log(error && error.json && error.json.message || error.json || error || 'no error');
}

showError();
error = { json: 'some error from json' };
showError();
error = { json: { message: 'some error from json.message' } };
showError();
```

And you can go as deep as you want. In angular, this would give

```
{{ error && error.json && error.json.message || error.json || error || 'no error' }}
```