# Call Async functions (Retunes Observable) from HTML template

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

Data displayed on HTML template is Key form data. Meaning, it needs to be translated.
For that purpose, I would like to call an Async function from my template. Tried this, with no success:

**Template:**

```
<span class="myClass-rowValue">{{translateServingStyle(size.defaultServingStyle?.surcharge) | async}}</span>
```

**Component ts file:**

```
servingStylesData$: Observable<ServingStyles_servingStyles[]>;

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.servingStylesData$ = of(this._apollo
      .watchQuery<ServingStyles>({
        query: ServingStylesQuery
      }))
      .pipe(
        filter((query) => !!query),
        switchMap((query) => query.valueChanges),
        take(1),
        takeUntil(this._ngOnDestroy),
        map((response) => response.data.servingStyles)
      );
}

translateServingStyle(servingStyleValue: string): Observable<string> {
    return this.servingStylesData$
      .pipe(
        map((servingStyles) => servingStyles
          .filter((servingStyle) => servingStyle.value === servingStyleValue)
          .map((selectedServingStyle) => selectedServingStyle.value)[0]
          )
      );
  }
```

What is the currect why of doing this?

**# Edit**

This is making my browser crash.
Getting into an endless loop calling **translateServingStyle()**

I have tried removing my function code, and just returning

```
of("some string")
```

and it works fine.

But when referencing a Pipe to a local Variable, this loop happens. Can anyone please explain why?

Comment: What's the issue you're facing exactly ?

Comment: give an example.like the whole object from which u trying to diplay, and mention what key is showing instead of what you want to show?.

Comment: My browser is getting stuck. It gets inside an endless loop calling this function... I have tried just returning an observable (Using of("some"string")) and it works fine. When passing down an observable saved as a local variable, this loop happens.

Comment: show servingStylesData function

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka Edited my question, and added servingStylesData

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**tl;dr**
Don't use the async pipe with function calls. This is expensive and long-running and can destroy the user experience or in your case crash your browser: Manage your observables yourself and not with the **easy to use** `async` pipe.

If you still want to use the `async` pipe with a function, you can try using the [ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush](https://netbasal.com/a-comprehensive-guide-to-angular-onpush-change-detection-strategy-5bac493074a4). This comes with other downsides, such as running the change detection manually, e.g. with `this.cdr.detectChanges();` and `cdr` being of type `ChangeDetectorRef`.

---

Please be aware of how Angulars Lifecycle system works.

Since evaluated function values do not have an internal reference (which Angular uses to check whether values have changed or need to be updated), they won't be checked by the lifecycle hook `ngOnChanges`, but rather with `ngDoCheck`, which runs **a lot of times**.

This is especially bad with pipes, and the worst with the async pipe. If we call your usage of `async` pipes expensive and long running, Angular states, that:

> An expensive and long-running pipe could destroy the user experience

or in your case crash the browser.

Please find [this blog post](https://blog.appverse.io/why-it-is-a-bad-idea-to-use-methods-in-the-html-templates-with-angular-2-30d49f0d3b16) for further explanation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it does make things more clear. With that said, I am using ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush already, so not sure why is my function being recalled. What do you suggest instead? Is there no possibility of passing values from Template and manipulating then asynchronously?

Comment: Can you please create a stackblitz?. I'm missing context to solve this any further.

Comment: Ok I resolved this issue by accepting Its not best practice to use a function that retunes and observable. And created an Observable<Map> with all values needed for the template to work with a variable. Accepting this answer, tnx

Comment: Good solution. Otherwise, you can handle subscriptions manually instead of using the `async` pipe. But without a stackblitz I can't show you this solution.