# Angularfire await function in template freezes - how should this be done?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

When I call a function from the template, and that function has a result that is async, then I run into a problem with the template freezing.  The code is simple enough.

component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let value of values">
  {{getCount(value)}}
</div>
```

component.js

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  getValues.subscribe(values => {
    this.values = values;
  })
}

async getCount(value) {
  let collRef = collection(this.afs, 'collection');
  const q = query(collRef, where("field", "==", value));
  return await getCountFromServer(q).data().count;
}
```

Comment: may be try async pipe like this {{getCount(value) | async}}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call Async functions (Retunes Observable) from HTML template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54980693/call-async-functions-retunes-observable-from-html-template)

Comment: I was going to mention in the original question - async pipe does NOT help.  Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid call function in template. Move this logic to service and work with result array in template. Current approach is stuck - it is because change detector trigger this func in loop. Just add console.log() to getCount(value) and check result.